# How would i make my google map zoom in to my current location?

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-1

Hi i would like to make my map zoom into my current location.
This current location is defined currently by sending lat and long to the emulator.
How would i go about doing this?

My current mapactivity.java

```
public class MapsActivity extends MapActivity {

    private MapView mapView;
    private MyLocationOverlay myLocOverlay;
    MapController mc;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.mapactivity);
        initMap();
        initMyLocation();


    }

    /**
     * Initialise the map and adds the zoomcontrols to the LinearLayout.
     */
    private void initMap() {
        mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);

        View zoomView = mapView.getZoomControls();
        LinearLayout myzoom = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.zoom);
        myzoom.addView(zoomView);
        mapView.displayZoomControls(true);
        mapView.getController().setZoom(17);
    }

    /**
     * Initialises the MyLocationOverlay and adds it to the overlays of the map
     */
    private void initMyLocation() {
        myLocOverlay = new MyLocationOverlay(this, mapView);
        myLocOverlay.enableMyLocation();
        mapView.getOverlays().add(myLocOverlay);

    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        return false;
    }
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to implement onLocationChanged(). In my code I've added the overlays here too. As a minimum you need to setCenter() with your current location

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

   List<Overlay> overlays = mapView.getOverlays();
   myLocOverlay = new MyLocationOverlay(this, mapView);
   overlays.add(myLocOverlay);
   myLocOverlay.enableMyLocation();*

   // definitely need what's below
   int lat = (int) (location.getLatitude() * 1E6);
   int lng = (int) (location.getLongitude() * 1E6);
   GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(lat, lng);
   mc.setCenter(point);
   mapView.invalidate();

}
```

Comment: This doesn't work. After i send the lat and long values, the marker on the map moves but it doesnt automatically move to the marker.

Comment: I didn't know that you had a marker. This makes the map centre to your current location. If the first answer does what you need, then stick with it.

Comment: No i don't have a marker. But my code places an overlay when i send the lat and long over. What i would like to find out is how would i make the android phone load my current location when i start up the program.

Comment: I enable the gps with lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE); then   lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 30000, 100, this);                                                                  (30 secs, 100 metres) - this enables the location listener

Comment: So i have to add lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE); then lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 30000, 100, this); (30 secs, 100 metres) - in the onLocationChanged?

Comment: No, put that outside the listener, somewhere like onCreate()

Comment: Have a look at http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidLocationAPI/article.html   This is a tutorial with a locationListener in. Some tutorials don't have that.

Comment: What version of the API is this? MapView doesn't have an onLocationChanged().

Answer (score 9):

Try adding this at the end of your initMyLocation code:

```
controller = mapView.getController();
mMyLocOverlay.runOnFirstFix(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                controller.setZoom(17);
                controller.animateTo(mMyLocOverlay.getMyLocation());
            }
        });
```

You can remove this line from your initMap method:

```
mapView.getController().setZoom(17);
```

Let me know if that works

Ger

Comment: An afterthought: This is unsafe as you are modifying the UI whilst not on that thread.  Look into wrapping it in something like this: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29

Answer (score 1):

Since you have your location data already you can create a LatLng Object/Structure and use this line directly on the Map object:

```
map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 15.0f));
```

I use the Android Google Maps API v2